# DevExpress ASPxGridView callbacks and jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

we have a DevExpress ASPxGridView in our webapp with EnableCallbacks=true to allow client side events for this grid. As soon as we include jQuery (1.4.1 or 1.4.2) and perform eg. a filtering on the ASPxGridView, all client-side grid functionality stop working.

We have tried the solution discussed here

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B144365.aspx

but to no avail.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem that might point us in the right direction?

Thanks in advance
Stijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a project with jQuery 1.4.2 and ASPxGridView.  Everything works properly.  The problem might appear because you are using some java script methods which break our code.  To be able to help you, we need a sample project showing this issue.  Please post a sample project to the [support center](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/) and we will do our best to help you.

Comment: We added a sample project at the devexpress support center and got an answer the same day. Great support!

Comment: You are always welcome :).  Don't you mind if we post a direct link to this DevExpress Support Center ticket here?

Comment: Not at all, I'll even do it myself :-) - http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=B191887